# Magento - Single Database, Multiple Sites

Tags: database

I want to know whether the below is possible with Magento and what I would need to do to set this up.

**The Scenario**

I have a Magento website. My Magento site has Categories, Sub Level Categories and Products. There are multiple resellers of my products and I would like each of them to have a basic website that includes all of my categories, sub level categories and products, fed from my websites database, however with each of their own websites I would like them to have the ability to change a product price and product part number on their own site.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: just to confirm: The resellers can login into your Magento admin and you want them to only change the product price and the product "part number" for their website?

Comment: No. I would want each of my resellers to have their own domain. Their admin panel would need to cater for the ability to change product price and part number. They will also need the ability to upload a new header, footer and homepage banner. They would receive their own orders and deal with accordingly, when they receive their orders (on their own site) it adjusts the overall stock level in my database.

Answer (score 1):

This is fully possible but not out of the box.

You have one main store that is in effect a B2B store that only serves the client stores. This main store is 'god' when it comes to stock level but local client stores can go their own way with prices and product descriptions.

So the satellite stores report their sales to your base and the stock figures are adjusted accordingly. There also has to be a means of checking the master stock records at other times, so things do not get out of sync.

You will need a client module to report the sales up stream and receive regular product updates. On your master store you will need to listen to these updates and amend the stock accordingly.

There are also the edge cases of credit memos and other scenarios where the stock keeping could get out of sync with what is physically in the warehouse.

So, as per the original question, entirely do-able. But you will have to write some code, do a lot of testing and refining of the requirements.

Comment: Presumably each reseller will still require their own admin panel?

Comment: Yep, each seller will have their own db and logins. Whether you give them full admin or not is another matter.